# ¿Cómo puedo evaluar una inecuación con dos desigualdades en python?

Tags: python

Intento evaluar una inecuación con dos desigualdades en python `20 < 3x + 5 < 26`.

Con sympy intento determinarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
`20 < 3x + 5 < 26`
     `3x + 5 < 26`
```

De tal modo que dentro de la sintaxis de sympy queda:

```
solve_rational_inequalities([[
    ((20, Poly(3x + 5 <)), '<'),
    ((Poly(3x + 5 <), 26),  '<')]])
```

Pero al momento de evaluarlo, me arroja el error de `ValueError: For efficiency reasons, poly should be a Poly instance`
Aquí el código completo:

```
from sympy.solvers.inequalities import reduce_rational_inequalities
from sympy.solvers.inequalities import solve_poly_inequalities
from sympy.polys import Poly
from sympy.abc import x
x = Symbol('x', real=True)
solve_rational_inequalities([[
    ((20, Poly(3x + 5 <)), '<'),
    ((Poly(3x + 5 <), 26),  '<')]])
```

¿Hay alguna manera de solucionar este problema? De antemano muchas gracias. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué tal si divides la desigualdad `20 < 3x + 5 < 26` en dos: `20 < 3x + 5` y `3x + 5 < 26`?

Comment: Bueno, técnicamente eso sí funciona con `reduce_rational_inequalities([[20 < 3*x + 5]], x)` y `reduce_rational_inequalities([[3*x + 5 < 26]], x)`, pero la idea como tal es tomarla desde una sola inecuación

Comment: Bueno, a menos que encuentres una mejor solución, es una buena opción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una expresión regular para "partir" tu inecuación doble en dos inecuaciones separadas, así (explicaciones después):

```
import re
ineq = "20 < 3*x + 5 < 26"

partes = re.split(r"([<>]=?)", ineq)
eq1= "".join(partes[:3])
eq2 = "".join(partes[-3:])
print(eq1)
print(eq2)
```

Como ves el truco es la expresión regular `([<>]=?)` que significa lo siguiente:

- Los paréntesis, que vamos a crear un grupo de captura. Eso causará que `re.split()` además de retornar los "trozos" resultantes, también retorne los "separadores" entre trozos (que son los signos de desigualdad de las inecuaciones)
- Los corchetes `[<>]` que puede aparecer cualquiera de los dos signos `<` o `>`
- El igual con interrogante `=?` que puede aparecer opcionalmente un signo igual (para que admita como separador `>=` y `<=`)

El resultado de `re.split()` va a ser una lista con cinco trozos, siempre que tu cadena de entrada tenga un par de comparadores de desigualdad. El primer trozo sería en este ejemplo el `"20 "`. El siguiente trozo sería el primer separador (`"<"` en el ejemplo) el siguiente trozo sería en este caso " 3*x +5"`. El siguiente sería el segundo separador, de nuevo` "<"`en este ejemplo, y el cuarto y último trozo sería el`"26"`.

Los siguientes `.join()` reúnen los trozos adecuados para formar dos expresiones (inecuaciones). Uno con los tres primeros trozos, otro con los tres últimos. El resultado en `eq1` y `eq2` es:

```html
20 < 3*x + 5 
 3*x + 5 < 26
```

Una vez lo tenemos separado de esta forma, se puede usar `sympy` para que resuelva las dos inecuaciones, por ejemplo así:

```py
from sympy import solve, S
ineq = [S(eq) for eq in (eq1, eq2)]
intervals = solve(ineq, domain=S.Reals)
```

La solución hallada por sympy es una operación And entre dos intervalos y lo muestra así:

```
(5 < x) & (x < 7)
```

Si quieres reducirlo a "un solo intervalo" (que en este ejemplo sería `(5,7)`) de modo que puedas graficarlo con la técnica explicada [en esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/510763/7123) se podría calcular la intersección de esos dos intervalos con el intervalo `(-infinito, +infinito)`, por ejemplo así:

```
from sympy import Interval, solveset

solucion = Interval(float("-inf"), float("+inf"))
for interval in intervals.args:
  interval = solveset(interval, domain=S.Reals)
  solucion &= interval
```

Como ves comenzamos por crear el intervalo infinito, y luego iteramos por `intervals.args` (que son cada una de las desigualdades antes obtenidas con `solve()`), para volver a resolver las inecuaciones que plantea cada uno de ellos y así tener intervalos cuya intersección con `solucion` calculamos con el operador `&=`.

El resultado en `solucion` es un intervalo, concretamente `(5, 7)` en este caso, que ya puedes plotear con la solución antes mencionada.

**Nota:** Esta solución no es del todo general, dependiendo de la inecuación de entrada puede ser que al final no puedas obtener un solo intervalo-solución, sino dos si `solve()` genera dos desigualdades disjuntas.