# ¿Cómo puedo graficar un intervalo de inecuaciones en python?

Tags: python, math

Trato de graficar un intervalo de inecuaciones con `matplotlib`, quiero imprimir algo así:
[image: Intervalo de inecuación]

Pero no he podido ni siquiera acercarme a lo que intento hacer, pero he hecho un esfuerzo, de la siguiente manera obtengo la gráfica a partir de la inecuación:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
 
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
y = abs(-2*x-3>=13)
fig = plt.figure(figsize= (10,5))
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Y este es el resultado:
[image: Resultado]

He buscado en stackoverflow en inglés y no he encontrado tampoco nada que se asemeje a lo que estoy buscando en concreto. ¿Existe algún método o forma de realizar lo que intento hacer? De antemano muchas gracias. Saludos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para hacer una gráfica como la que pides tendrías que comenzar por "despejar la x" de tu desigualdad, de modo que puedas decir dónde comienza y dónde termina la flecha roja que quieres pintar en los ejes. Este trabajo deberías hacerlo tú, pues dejar que lo haga Python puede ser muy complejo. Por ejemplo, en la desigualdad que tú planteas (-2x-3>=13) si despejas te queda x<=-8. Con esta información sabemos que queremos pintar una flecha que empiece en -8 y señale a la izquierda.

Pero aún sabiendo esto, para lograr el plot todavía hay que saber muchos trucos de matplotlib como los siguientes:

- Cómo eliminar todos los ejes que matplotlib pinta por defecto alrededor del plot
- Cómo colocar un eje X horizontal que pase por cero
- Cómo poner ticks en el eje X a intervalos de 1 unidad y que las marquitas de los ticks sean más largas de lo normal.
- Cómo dibujar una línea roja (o de otro color) entre dos puntos cualesquiera del espacio de coordenadas
- Cómo añadir una punta de flecha (o un triángulo que mire a izquierda o a derecha) en cualquier punto del eje x
- Cómo añadir un círculo rojo (o de otro color) en cualquier punto del eje X para marcar el extremo del intervalo, y cómo rellenar ese círculo de blanco o no según queramos marcar que el intervalo es abierto o cerrado en ese punto.
- Cómo hacer que estas cosas que hemos pintado en rojo (líneas, triángulos, círculos) aparezcan *encima* de los ejes (es decir, "tapándolos") y no debajo que es donde matplotlib las pintaría por defecto.

Todo esto es muy largo de explicar, por lo que me voy a limitar a darte el código de la función que lo hace todo (con comentarios para que no sea tan misterioso). La función recibe muchos parámetros pero todos ellos tienen valores por defecto. Más adelante daré ejemplos de cómo usarla para mostrar diferentes intervalos.

```py
def plot_interval(title="Intervalo", start=float("-inf"), end=float("+inf"), start_open=False, end_open=False, x_axis=(-10, 10), color="red"):
  """Parámetros:
   - title: Lo que aparecerá encima de la gráfica
   - start: punto de la izquierda del intervalo a mostrar. Si no se especifica
       se usará -infinito
   - end: punto de la derecha del intervalo a mostrar. Si no se espeficica
       se usará +infinito
   - start_open, end_open: booleanos que indican si esos extremos son abiertos
       (por defecto son cerrados). Eso afecta al círculo que los representa
   - x_axis: valores a mostrar en el eje x, sobre los que se pintará el
       intervalo (por defecto el eje x va de -10 a +10)
   - color: color de la línea, flecha y círculo que representa el intervalo
  """

  # Crear la figura
  fig = plt.figure(figsize= (10,1))
  ax = fig.add_subplot(aspect=1)

  # Eliminar todos los bordes y preparar el eje x
  for borde in ["left", "top", "right"]:
    ax.spines[borde].set_visible(False)
  ax.spines["bottom"].set_position(("data", 0))
  ax.set_xticks(range(x_axis[0], x_axis[1]+1))
  ax.set_xlim(*x_axis)
  ax.tick_params(which="major", axis="x", direction="inout", length=8)

  # Dimensionar eje Y y quitarle los ticks
  ax.set_yticks([])
  ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)

  # Preparar algunas variables según los extremos de los intervalos
  # sean infinito o no. Las variables que se preparan son:
  # x0, x1 (puntos de inicio y fin de la línea roja)
  # x0shape, x1shape (si hay que poner un triángulo o círculo en cada extremo)
  if start==float("-inf"):
    x0 = x_axis[0]      # Punto en que comienza la linea roja
    x0shape = "arrow"
  else:
    x0 = start
    x0shape = "circle"
  if end==float("+inf"):
    x1 = x_axis[1]
    x1shape = "arrow"
  else:
    x1 = end
    x1shape = "circle"

  # Pintar la línea roja. El zorder=3 hará que se pinte encima del eje
  ax.plot((x0, x1), (0,0), color=color, clip_on=False, zorder=3)

  # Pintar los extremos del intervalo
  if x0shape == "arrow":
    # Si hay que pintar flecha, se pinta un triángulo ("<k")
    # El zorder=4 hará que se pinte encima de la línea roja
    ax.plot(x0, 0, "<k", color=color, markersize=10, clip_on=False, zorder=4)
  else:
    # Si no hay que pintar flecha, se pinta un círculo
    # facecolor es el color de relleno, que depende de si el extremo es abierto o cerrado
    c = plt.Circle((x0, 0), 0.2, edgecolor=color, facecolor="white" if start_open else color, clip_on=False, zorder=4)
    ax.add_patch(c)
  if x1shape == "arrow":
    ax.plot(x1, 0, "k>", color=color, markersize=10, clip_on=False, zorder=4)
  else:
    c = plt.Circle((x1, 0), 0.2, edgecolor=color, facecolor="white" if end_open else color, clip_on=False, zorder=4)
    ax.add_patch(c)

  # Finalmente añadimos el título
  ax.set_title(title)
  return ax
```

### Ejemplos de uso

Nota, siempre paso un título a todos los casos y uso fórmulas TeX en el título, de ahí los signos de dólar. Observa también que no es necesario especificar todos los parámetros. Los que no se ponen toman su valor por defecto.

```
plot_interval(r"$(-\infty, \infty)$")
```

[image: Infinito]

```
plot_interval(r"$(-\infty, -5)$", end=-5, end_open=True)
```

[image: (-infinito, -5)]

```
plot_interval(r"$[3, \infty)$", start=3)
```

[image: 3 a infinito]

```
plot_interval(r"$[3, 6)$", start=3, end=6, end_open=True, x_axis=(0,10))
```

[image: tres a seis]

Y finalmente, el caso de tu ejemplo:

```
plot_interval(r"$-2x-3\geq13$", end=-8, x_axis=(-12,2))
```

[image: desigualdad]

### Bonus. Dejando que Sympy resuelva la desigualdad

Si te parece muy complicado despejar tú mismo la `x` de la desigualdad, puedes instalar Sympy, que es un procesador simbólico matemático de capacidades similares en cierta forma a las de Wolfram-Alpha.

Además, es muy sencillo integrar la solución que te da Sympy con la función que he mostrado antes. He aquí un ejemplo (fíjate que he usado `>` en vez de `>=` para que veas que se pinta correctamente el intervalo abierto):

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy import solveset, S, latex

ineq = parse_expr("-2*x-3 > 13")
interval = solveset(ineq, domain=S.Reals)

plot_interval(title=latex(ineq, mode="inline"),  
              start=interval.start, end=interval.end, 
              start_open=interval.left_open, end_open=interval.right_open,
              x_axis=(-12, 5),
              color="coral")
```

Resultado:

[image: Con Sympy]

Comment: Muchas gracias abulafia, solo tengo una pequeña duda. Al momento de intentar mostrar la gráfica de `plot_interval` del primer código no me muestra nada. Y en el segundo código de `sympy` me arroja `NameError: name 'plot_interval' is not defined`

Comment: Respecto a lo primero, quizás necesites un `plt.show()` dependiendo de dónde lo ejecutes (yo he hecho las pruebas en Google Colab y allí no es necesario). Respecto a lo segundo, la función `plot_interval()` no está predefinida, es la que yo dí para el primer código, que por tanto debería formar parte también del segundo código (o importarlo desde otro .py) También puede ser necesario un `plt.show()` para el segundo caso.

Comment: Ya lo he intentado y aún no me funciona :/

Comment: Puedes pegar el código completo que estás intentando en un pastebin y compartir el enlace para que pueda ver yo si te falta algo?

Comment: Bueno, realmente copié el primer código como tal y escribí al final `plt.show()` y nada. Solo trato de ejecutarlo en la consola de cmd con python, no con Google colab

Comment: Pero entonces ¿copiaste solo la definicion de la funcion? No copiaste tambien (fuera de ella) uno de los ejemplos de cómo llamarla, p.ej. `plot_interval(r"$-2x-3\geq13$", end=-8, x_axis=(-12,2))` ?

Comment: Este es el código tal cual lo hice en mi consola y no me arroja nada: https://pastebin.com/6b727nm4

Comment: Como me temía, has metido la llamada a la función dentro de la propia función, en vez de fuera. Además te faltan los import necesarios al principio (que no puse en mi respuesta porque supuse que eran conocidos), y el plt.show(). La cosa debe quedar como aqui -> https://pastebin.com/MCRaATnx

Comment: Funciona, muchas gracias!

Comment: Abulafia, tengo otra duda, cuando intento definir una inecuación, supongamos `-29 ≤ -17 - 3x < 22` en la variable `ineq = parse_expr("-29 ≤ -17 - 3x < 22")` me arroja un error, a qué se debe?

Comment: Si tienes otra duda, puedes hacer otra pregunta @UlisesAntonioChávez

Comment: Sí, estoy de acuerdo con @DanteS., esta última duda ya no está relacionada con la pregunta original (que era sobre la gráfica), sino con sympy. Creo que deberías hacer una pregunta nueva (en la que puedes incluir un enlace a ésta). Ya la respuesta es bastante larga como está, así como este hilo de comentarios.

Comment: De hecho ya lo había preguntado dos veces: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4365375/how-can-i-define-an-inequality-in-sympy?noredirect=1#comment9118259_4365375 y https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510073/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-evaluar-una-inecuaci%c3%b3n-con-dos-desigualdades-en-python?noredirect=1#comment906271_510073

Comment: Disculpa Ulises, no había visto esa otra pregunta tuya. Acabo de responderte con una idea que quizás te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Lo que podrías hacer es generar un arreglo donde todos los valores de 'Y' sean cero así podrás tener una gráfica sobre el eje 'X'

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
val = 0
fig = plt.figure(figsize= (10,5))
plt.plot(x, np.zeros_like(x) + val, '->')
plt.show()
```

El código es simple, `val = 0` es la posición sobre el eje 'Y' donde deseas que se muestre la gráfica

`np.zeros_like(x)` define un arreglo donde todos los valores para 'Y' son cero. funciona de forma similar a `np.zeros` pero la ventaja de `zeros_like` es que puedes indicar la "forma" o el caracter que mostrará la gráfica en este caso `->` mostrará una flecha apuntando a la derecha (Que podrías utilizar para indicar la dirección)