# ¿Cómo puedo graficar un intervalo de inecuaciones con solo dos términos en python?

Tags: python, math

Anteriormente había realizado esta pregunta en [¿Cómo puedo graficar un intervalo de inecuaciones en python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510751/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-graficar-un-intervalo-de-inecuaciones-en-python) donde se graficaba una inecuación con una cantidad definida de números:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en esta ocasión intento desarrollar algo como lo que está en la siguiente gráfica, es decir sin que tenga todos los números marcados antes de llegar a los dos términos, resultados de la inecuación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anteriormente @Abulafia me lo había explicado, pero no he podido editar más allá de lo que me dejó en el código anterior. Me fue de mucha ayuda, pero al momento de hacer la inecuación con valores más grandes, no se imprimen correctamente, es decir, los dos términos no salen en la imagen cuando son demasiado grandes, observen el error:
[image: Error de la inecuación]

Código entero:

```
ef plot_interval(title="Intervalo", start=float("-inf"), end=float("+inf"), start_open=False, end_open=False, x_axis=(-10, 10), color="red"):
  """Parámetros:
   - title: Lo que aparecerá encima de la gráfica
   - start: punto de la izquierda del intervalo a mostrar. Si no se especifica
       se usará -infinito
   - end: punto de la derecha del intervalo a mostrar. Si no se espeficica
       se usará +infinito
   - start_open, end_open: booleanos que indican si esos extremos son abiertos
       (por defecto son cerrados). Eso afecta al círculo que los representa
   - x_axis: valores a mostrar en el eje x, sobre los que se pintará el
       intervalo (por defecto el eje x va de -10 a +10)
   - color: color de la línea, flecha y círculo que representa el intervalo
  """

  # Crear la figura
  fig = plt.figure(figsize= (10,1))
  ax = fig.add_subplot(aspect=1)

  # Eliminar todos los bordes y preparar el eje x
  for borde in ["left", "top", "right"]:
    ax.spines[borde].set_visible(False)
  ax.spines["bottom"].set_position(("data", 0))
  ax.set_xticks(range(x_axis[0], x_axis[1]+1))
  ax.set_xlim(*x_axis)
  ax.tick_params(which="major", axis="x", direction="inout", length=8)

  # Dimensionar eje Y y quitarle los ticks
  ax.set_yticks([])
  ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)

  # Preparar algunas variables según los extremos de los intervalos
  # sean infinito o no. Las variables que se preparan son:
  # x0, x1 (puntos de inicio y fin de la línea roja)
  # x0shape, x1shape (si hay que poner un triángulo o círculo en cada extremo)
  if start==float("-inf"):
    x0 = x_axis[0]      # Punto en que comienza la linea roja
    x0shape = "arrow"
  else:
    x0 = start
    x0shape = "circle"
  if end==float("+inf"):
    x1 = x_axis[1]
    x1shape = "arrow"
  else:
    x1 = end
    x1shape = "circle"

  # Pintar la línea roja. El zorder=3 hará que se pinte encima del eje
  ax.plot((x0, x1), (0,0), color=color, clip_on=False, zorder=3)

  # Pintar los extremos del intervalo
  if x0shape == "arrow":
    # Si hay que pintar flecha, se pinta un triángulo ("<k")
    # El zorder=4 hará que se pinte encima de la línea roja
    ax.plot(x0, 0, "<k", color=color, markersize=10, clip_on=False, zorder=4)
  else:
    # Si no hay que pintar flecha, se pinta un círculo
    # facecolor es el color de relleno, que depende de si el extremo es abierto o cerrado
    c = plt.Circle((x0, 0), 0.2, edgecolor=color, facecolor="white" if start_open else color, clip_on=False, zorder=4)
    ax.add_patch(c)
  if x1shape == "arrow":
    ax.plot(x1, 0, "k>", color=color, markersize=10, clip_on=False, zorder=4)
  else:
    c = plt.Circle((x1, 0), 0.2, edgecolor=color, facecolor="white" if end_open else color, clip_on=False, zorder=4)
    ax.add_patch(c)

  # Finalmente añadimos el título
  ax.set_title(title)
  return ax
```

Agradezco mucho su apoyo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Es decir, ¿De lo que puso Abulafia en tu pregunta anterior no has intentado nada?

Comment: Sí, sí he intentado, pero no he conseguido que funcione, de hecho, el código funciona peor. Sin embargo, las modificaciones que quiero, no las puede conseguir. El código que he modificado (hace unos meses atrás) lo dejo aquí, este sí funciona correctamente, y no lo puse porque no es parte fundamental de la pregunta: https://pastebin.com/yra7iYxT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad son dos preguntas separadas:

### Cómo quitar los ticks del eje x

Los ticks los pone esta línea:

```py
    ax.set_xticks(range(x_axis[0], x_axis[1]+1))
```

y a ella se le pasa `range()` que genera todos los enteros en el rango que pinta el eje x. Se trata de cambiar esa lista de enteros por otra que sólo tenga los puntos de interés. Estos puntos serían los extremos del intervalo (`start` y `end`) y el cero, si es que aparece. Pero los extremos del intervalo, si son infinito, no deberían pintarse.

Entonces podemos escribir el siguiente código que compute esos puntos, y luego usarlos como ticks:

```py
    # Poner solo puntos clave, que serían los extremos del intervalo 
    # (siempre que no sean infinitos) y el cero
    t = [int(x) for x in (start, 0, end) if abs(x)<float("inf")]
    ax.set_xticks(t)
```

### ¿Por qué salen mal algunos casos?

Porque a la función hay que pasarle en el argumento `x_axis` el rango que quieres mostrar en el eje X, y si no se lo pasas toma por defecto (-10,10). En tu segundo ejemplo ese rango no es apropiado, pues el intervalo que quieres pintar va de menos infinito a -13. Así que tendrías que pasarle un rango de representación que incluya a ese intervalo, por ejemplo `(-18, 0)`

Pero esto abre otra pregunta interesante ¿no podría la propia función determinar qué rango mostrar según cuál sea el intervalo a representar? Se puede intentar una asignación automática del intervalo, pero hay que tomar algunas decisiones que pueden llevar a un resultado distinto de lo que el autor del dibujo querría, por lo que será mejor dejar la opción al autor de especificar otro rango.

Entonces se puede hacer que si el autor no especifica rango, el código lo calcule automáticamente, pero si el autor especifica un rango, que lo use. El siguiente código intenta elegir un rango razonable si el autor no puso otro:

```
  # Autodetectar rango a pintar
  if x_axis is None:
    x_axis = [0,0]
    x_axis[0] = start - 5
    x_axis[1] = end + 5
    if x_axis[0] == float("-inf"):
      x_axis[0] = min(x_axis[1]-10, -10)
    if x_axis[1] == float("+inf"):
      x_axis[1] = max(x_axis[0]+10, +10)
    x_axis=tuple(int(x) for x in x_axis)
```

Básicamente intenta una zona "alrededor" del intervalo a representar, 5 unidades más por la izquierda y por la derecha, con cuidado para el caso en que el intervalo tenga un extremo (o ambos) infinitos.

### Todo junto

Este sería el código completo de la nueva función:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_interval(title="Intervalo", start=float("-inf"), end=float("+inf"), 
                  start_open=False, end_open=False, x_axis=None, color="red",
                  ticks=True):
  """Parámetros:
   - title: Lo que aparecerá encima de la gráfica
   - start: punto de la izquierda del intervalo a mostrar. Si no se especifica
       se usará -infinito
   - end: punto de la derecha del intervalo a mostrar. Si no se espeficica
       se usará +infinito
   - start_open, end_open: booleanos que indican si esos extremos son abiertos
       (por defecto son cerrados). Eso afecta al círculo que los representa
   - x_axis: valores a mostrar en el eje x, sobre los que se pintará el
       intervalo. Si se pasa None (valor por defecto) estos límites son
       calculados de forma automática
   - color: color de la línea, flecha y círculo que representa el intervalo
   - ticks: booleano (por defecto True) para especificar si se desean
     ticks en todos los enteros del eje X, o solo en los extremos del
     intervalo representado y en el 0.
  """

  # Crear la figura
  fig = plt.figure(figsize= (10,1))
  ax = fig.add_subplot(aspect=1)

  # Autodetectar rango a pintar
  if x_axis is None:
    x_axis = [0,0]
    x_axis[0] = start - 5
    x_axis[1] = end + 5
    if x_axis[0] == float("-inf"):
      x_axis[0] = min(x_axis[1]-10, -10)
    if x_axis[1] == float("+inf"):
      x_axis[1] = max(x_axis[0]+10, +10)
    x_axis=tuple(int(x) for x in x_axis)

  # Eliminar todos los bordes y preparar el eje x
  for borde in ["left", "top", "right"]:
    ax.spines[borde].set_visible(False)
  ax.spines["bottom"].set_position(("data", 0))
  if ticks:
    # Poner todos los enteros en el rango a pintar
    ax.set_xticks(range(x_axis[0], x_axis[1]+1))
  else:
    # Poner solo puntos clave, que serían los extremos del intervalo 
    # (siempre que no sean infinitos) y el cero
    t = [int(x) for x in (start, 0, end) if abs(x)<float("inf")]
    ax.set_xticks(t)
  ax.set_xlim(*x_axis)
  ax.tick_params(which="major", axis="x", direction="inout", length=8)

  # Dimensionar eje Y y quitarle los ticks
  ax.set_yticks([])
  ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)

  # Preparar algunas variables según los extremos de los intervalos
  # sean infinito o no. Las variables que se preparan son:
  # x0, x1 (puntos de inicio y fin de la línea roja)
  # x0shape, x1shape (si hay que poner un triángulo o círculo en cada extremo)
  if start==float("-inf"):
    x0 = x_axis[0]      # Punto en que comienza la linea roja
    x0shape = "arrow"
  else:
    x0 = start
    x0shape = "circle"
  if end==float("+inf"):
    x1 = x_axis[1]
    x1shape = "arrow"
  else:
    x1 = end
    x1shape = "circle"

  # Pintar la línea roja. El zorder=3 hará que se pinte encima del eje
  ax.plot((x0, x1), (0,0), color=color, clip_on=False, zorder=3)

  # Pintar los extremos del intervalo
  if x0shape == "arrow":
    # Si hay que pintar flecha, se pinta un triángulo ("<k")
    # El zorder=4 hará que se pinte encima de la línea roja
    ax.plot(x0, 0, "<k", color=color, markersize=10, clip_on=False, zorder=4)
  else:
    # Si no hay que pintar flecha, se pinta un círculo
    # facecolor es el color de relleno, que depende de si el extremo es abierto o cerrado
    c = plt.Circle((x0, 0), 0.2, edgecolor=color, facecolor="white" if start_open else color, clip_on=False, zorder=4)
    ax.add_patch(c)
  if x1shape == "arrow":
    ax.plot(x1, 0, "k>", color=color, markersize=10, clip_on=False, zorder=4)
  else:
    c = plt.Circle((x1, 0), 0.2, edgecolor=color, facecolor="white" if end_open else color, clip_on=False, zorder=4)
    ax.add_patch(c)

  # Finalmente añadimos el título
  ax.set_title(title)
  return ax
```

### Ejemplos de uso

Por ejemplo, representemos el intervalo `(-2, 5)` abierto por ambos lados. Si no especificamos el nuevo parámetro `ticks`, saldrán todos los ticks como salían antes, y si queremos que muestre como antes el rango (-10, 10) en el eje, debemos ahora pasarle ese rango. Entonces la llamada sería la siguiente para producir exactamente el mismo resultado que producía el código original:

```py
plot_interval(r"$(-2, 5)$", start=-2, end=5, start_open=True, end_open=True, 
              x_axis=(-10, 10))
```

[image: Resultado]

Con el nuevo parámetro `ticks=False` podemos eliminar los ticks:

```
plot_interval(r"$(-2, 5)$", start=-2, end=5, start_open=True, end_open=True, 
              x_axis=(-10, 10), ticks=False)
```

[image: Resultado]

Si además omitimos `x_axis=(-10,10)` se usará el "autoajuste":

```py
plot_interval(r"$(-2, 5)$", start=-2, end=5, start_open=True, end_open=True, 
              ticks=False)
```

[image: Resutlado]

La omisión de los ticks y el autoajuste son parámetros independientes. Si quitamos `ticks=False` tenemos de nuevo los ticks, y el rango autoajustado:

```py
plot_interval(r"$(-2, 5)$", start=-2, end=5, start_open=True, end_open=True)
```

[image: Resultado]

El caso "especial" que antes salía mal, ahora saldrá de esta forma si no especificamos nada en `x_axis`:

```
plot_interval(title=latex(ineq, mode="inline"),  
              start=float("-inf"), end=-13, 
              start_open=True, end_open=False)
```

[image: Resultado]

Si quieres quitar los ticks, ya sabes, añades `ticks=False':

```py
plot_interval(title=latex(ineq, mode="inline"),  
              start=float("-inf"), end=-13, 
              start_open=True, end_open=False,
              ticks=False)
```

[image: Resultado]

Si bien ahora, debido a que el intervalo representado va de -18 a -8, el cero no aparece lo que puede ser un poco desorientador. Pero puedes forzar a que el eje x incluya el cero, especificando otro `x_axis`:

```
plot_interval(title=latex(ineq, mode="inline"),  
              start=float("-inf"), end=-13, 
              start_open=True, end_open=False,
              ticks=False, x_axis=(-16, 1))
```

[image: Resultado]

Como ves, hay mucha flexibilidad a la hora de elegir cómo quieres la gráfica, según cómo uses los parámetros de la función.

Comment: `(start, 0, end)` Esa sintaxis no la conocía. ¿De donde salió?

Comment: @CandidMoe Es una vulgar tupla con tres elementos :-)

Comment: Oh! ... se me había ocurrido que era una versión compacta de `range()` o alguna sintaxis nueva >3.8. Yo siempre uso listas, no tuplas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a implementar, me sirve bastantísimo para las clases de aritmética básica que doy, gracias!

Comment: bastantísimo :-)

Comment: @abulafia Dentro del parámetro `plot_interval(title=latex(ineq, mode="inline")...` ¿se puede añadir dos intervalos? es decir: `("-inf"), end=-13` y `(10), end="inf"`

Comment: Intenté esto, pero no me funciona: `start=(float("-inf"),10), end=(-13,float("inf"))`

Comment: No. Esta función sólo pinta un intervalo. Hacer que pinte un número arbitrario de ellos puede ser complicado, especialmente si se solapan entre sí. Si no se solapan puede ser más sencillo, pero en todo caso requeriría de cambios bastante profundos en el código. Deberías crear una nueva pregunta para esto.

Comment: Bueno, arbitrariamente cogería diez mil iteraciones y las que pasen por un filtro serían aptas para poder ser elegidas, pero la pregunta en sí, va de intentar no solapar ambos intervalos. De igual, me abro la pregunta