# ¿Cómo puedo graficar dos intérvalos en una inecuación con plot_interval?

Tags: python, math

En base al a pregunta anterior de [¿Cómo puedo graficar un intervalo de inecuaciones con solo dos términos en python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/542816/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-graficar-un-intervalo-de-inecuaciones-con-solo-dos-t%C3%A9rminos-en-pytho) y con la sugerencia de @abulafia, he abierto esta nueva pregunta para consultar cómo graficar dos intervalos con `plot_interval`.

Me surgió la duda de intentar meter dos intervalos en una inecuación, es decir `[-13, -∞) U (10, ∞)`, tomando como principio `start=float("-inf"), end=-13` y tratando de obtener dicho resultado.
Trato de evitar que se solapen ambas imagenes mediante un filtro de selección (`[-13, -∞) U [-10, -∞)` y se obtengan este tipo de inecuaciones raras) y quiero unificar ambas inecuaciones anteriormente comentadas:
[image: -13, -∞)]
[image: (10, ∞)]

Y unirlo en una sola:
[image: Unido]

Traté de modificar el código:

```
plot_interval(title=latex(ineq, mode="inline"),  
              start=float("-inf"), end=-13, 
              start_open=True, end_open=False,
              ticks=False, x_axis=(-16, 1))
```

Por lo siguiente:

```
start=(float("-inf"),10), end=(-13,float("inf"))
```

Y me explicaron que para poder lograr este tipo de objetivo, requeriría cambios profundos en el código, entonces me gustaría saber la explicación de cómo puede funcionar o no funcionar lo que trato de realizar.

De antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: Referencia: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/542816/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-graficar-un-intervalo-de-inecuaciones-con-solo-dos-t%c3%a9rminos-en-pytho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función que estás usando (que escribí yo como respuesta a otra pregunta tuya), estaba diseñada para graficar un solo intervalo. Si se quisieran graficar varios, sería necesario pasarle a la función una lista de intervalos y la función tendría que iterar internamente para ir pintando cada uno de los intervalos. Es decir, la parte que pintaba el intervalo en sí, debería estar dentro de un bucle.

Pero pintar los intervalos es la parte más sencilla de este problema. Aparecen otros asuntos adicionales:

1. ¿Cómo determinar automáticamente el rango de representación del eje X cuando se tienen varios intervalos?. Si los intervalos no son infinitos se puede tomar el mínimo de todos los lados izquierdos y el máximo de todos los derechos para en base a ellos decidir la x mínima y la máxima. Pero si hay intervalos infinitos la cosa se complica.
2. ¿Cómo pintar intervalos que se solapen? Ya que un intervalo se pinta con una línea roja sobre el eje X, si se solapan no se verá claramente dónde empieza y acaba cada uno. Habría que desplazarlos verticalmente
3. ¿Cómo simplificar el paso de parámetros cuando tenemos que crear varios intervalos?

Empezando por la última, podemos definir una clase para guardar los datos relacionados con un intervalo particular:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Interval:
  start: float = float("-inf")
  end: float = float("+inf")
  left_open: bool = True
  right_open: bool = True
```

Así, para representar un intervalo abierto por ambos lados entre 2 y 5 podemos poner `Interval(2,5)`. Y si lo queremos cerrado por la izquierda sería `Interval(2,5, False, True)`, y del mismo modo cerrado por la derecha sería `Interval(2,5, True, False)` y cerrado por ambos lados sería `Interval(2,5, False, False)`

Eso nos permitirá simplificar la función a la que ya no habría que pasar separadamente los extremos de los intervalos y si están abiertos o no, sino una lista de objetos de tipo `Interval`. Con ello tu primer ejemplo de código se pondría ahora así:

```
plot_interval(title=latex(ineq, mode="inline"),  
              intervals=[Interval(float("-inf"), -13, True, False)],
              ticks=False, x_axis=(-16, 1))
```

y el segundo ejemplo se pondría así:

```
plot_interval(title=latex(ineq, mode="inline"),  
              intervals=[
                  Interval(float("-inf"), 10, True, False),
                  Interval(-13, float("inf"), False, True),
              ],
              ticks=False)
```

naturalmente hay que reescribir la función para que admita ahora una lista, y para que la procese apropiadamente.

Para el segundo problema (solape de intervalos) añadiré otro parámetro a la función que permita especificar la separación vertical entre intervalos. Por defecto será 0 para que los pinte todos sobre el eje X, pero si lo cambias a 0.3 cada intervalo pintado saldrá un poco más arriba que el anterior, evitando que se mezclen.

Para el primer problema (elección automática del rango en el eje x) se me ha ocurrido el siguiente algoritmo que he probado y parece ir bastante bien:

```py
  ptos = []
  for i in intervals:
    for e in (i.start, i.end):
      if abs(e)!=float("inf"):
        ptos.append(int(e))
  # Y usarlos para decidir el rango x a pintar
  if x_axis is None:
    if ptos:
      x_axis = [min(ptos)-5, max(ptos)+5]
    else:
      x_axis = [-10, 10]
```

Básicamente consiste en recoger todos los extremos de intervalos distintos de ±∞ en una lista, para luego tomar el mínimo y máximo de la misma. Si la lista está vacía (todos los extremos eran infinitos) se elige arbitrariamente que los límites del eje vayan de -10 a 10.

### Solución final

Este es el código que implementa las ideas antes explicadas:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Interval:
  start: float = float("-inf")
  end: float = float("+inf")
  left_open: bool = True
  right_open: bool = True


def plot_interval(title="Intervalo", intervals=Interval(), x_axis=None, color="red",
                  ticks=True, vsep=0):
  """Parámetros:
   - title: Lo que aparecerá encima de la gráfica
   - intervals: lista de objetos Interval a representar
   - x_axis: valores a mostrar en el eje x, sobre los que se pintará el
       intervalo (por defecto se computan automáticamente)
   - color: color de la línea, flecha y círculo que representa el intervalo
   - ticks: booleano que indica si mostrar todos los ticks o no
   - vsep: separación vertical cuando se pintan varios intervalos
  """

  # Si solo se quiere pintar un intervalo se puede pasar éste
  # sin necesidad de crear una lista de un solo elemento. En este condicional
  # lo convertimos en esa lista
  if type(intervals) != list:
    intervals = [intervals]

  # Recoger todos los extremos de intervalos que no sean infinitos
  ptos = []
  for i in intervals:
    for e in (i.start, i.end):
      if abs(e)!=float("inf"):
        ptos.append(int(e))
  # Y usarlos para decidir el rango x a pintar
  if x_axis is None:
    if ptos:
      x_axis = [min(ptos)-5, max(ptos)+5]
    else:
      x_axis = [-10, 10]

  # Crear la figura
  fig = plt.figure(figsize= (10,1))
  ax = fig.add_subplot(aspect=1)

  # Eliminar todos los bordes y preparar el eje x
  for borde in ["left", "top", "right"]:
    ax.spines[borde].set_visible(False)
  ax.spines["bottom"].set_position(("data", 0))
  if ticks:
    # Poner todos los enteros en el rango a pintar
    ax.set_xticks(range(x_axis[0], x_axis[1]+1))
  else:
    # Poner solo puntos clave, que serían los extremos del intervalo 
    # (siempre que no sean infinitos) y el cero
    t = [float(x) for i in intervals for x in (i.start, i.end) if abs(x)<float("inf") ]
    t+=[0]
    ax.set_xticks(t)
  ax.set_xlim(*x_axis)
  ax.tick_params(which="major", axis="x", direction="inout", length=8)

  # Dimensionar eje Y y quitarle los ticks
  ax.set_yticks([])
  ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)

  # Preparar algunas variables según los extremos de los intervalos
  # sean infinito o no. Las variables que se preparan son:
  # x0, x1 (puntos de inicio y fin de la línea roja)
  # x0shape, x1shape (si hay que poner un triángulo o círculo en cada extremo)
  for y, i in enumerate(intervals):
    y = y*vsep  # Separar verticalmente las líneas de los intervalos
    start, end = i.start, i.end
    start_open, end_open = i.left_open, i.right_open
    if start==float("-inf"):
      x0 = x_axis[0]      # Punto en que comienza la linea roja
      x0shape = "arrow"
    else:
      x0 = start
      x0shape = "circle"
    if end==float("+inf"):
      x1 = x_axis[1]
      x1shape = "arrow"
    else:
      x1 = end
      x1shape = "circle"

    # Pintar la línea roja. El zorder=3 hará que se pinte encima del eje
    ax.plot((x0, x1), (y,y), color=color, clip_on=False, zorder=3)

    # Pintar los extremos del intervalo
    if x0shape == "arrow":
      # Si hay que pintar flecha, se pinta un triángulo ("<k")
      # El zorder=4 hará que se pinte encima de la línea roja
      ax.plot(x0, y, "<k", color=color, markersize=10, clip_on=False, zorder=4)
    else:
      # Si no hay que pintar flecha, se pinta un círculo
      # facecolor es el color de relleno, que depende de si el extremo es abierto o cerrado
      c = plt.Circle((x0, y), 0.2, edgecolor=color, facecolor="white" if start_open else color, clip_on=False, zorder=4)
      ax.add_patch(c)
    if x1shape == "arrow":
      ax.plot(x1, y, "k>", color=color, markersize=10, clip_on=False, zorder=4)
    else:
      c = plt.Circle((x1, y), 0.2, edgecolor=color, facecolor="white" if end_open else color, clip_on=False, zorder=4)
      ax.add_patch(c)

  # Finalmente añadimos el título
  ax.set_title(title)
  return ax
```

### Demos

Por defecto se sigue comportando como la función que tenías antes, salvo que ahora el intervalo se le pasa con la nueva sintaxis. Así, por ejemplo:

```
plot_interval(title=latex(ineq, mode="inline"),  
              intervals=[Interval(float("-inf"), -13, True, False)],
              ticks=False, x_axis=(-16, 1))
```

produce el resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Pero ahora se le pueden pasar varios intervalos. Si no se solapan, es mejor no tocar el parámetro `vsep` y dejarlo con su valor por defecto 0:

```
plot_interval("$(x\leq -13) \cup (x\geq10)$", 
              intervals=[
                         Interval(float("-inf"),-13,True,False), 
                         Interval(10,float("inf"), False, True)
                         ],
              x_axis=None, ticks=False)
```

[image: Result]

Pero si se solapan, el valor 0 por defecto hace que no se pueda leer bien la gráfica:

```
plot_interval("$(x\leq -10) \cup (x\geq-13)$", 
              intervals=[
                         Interval(float("-inf"),10,True,False), 
                         Interval(-13,float("inf"), False, True)
                         ],
              x_axis=None, ticks=False)
```

[image: Resultado mal]

lo que se arregla añadiendo `vsep=0.3`:

```
plot_interval("$(x\leq -10) \cup (x\geq-13)$", 
              intervals=[
                         Interval(float("-inf"),10,True,False), 
                         Interval(-13,float("inf"), False, True)
                         ],
              x_axis=None, ticks=False, vsep=0.3)
```

[image: Resultado bien]

### Bonus

La dataclass que he definido, `Interval`, resulta ser compatible con el tipo retornado por `simpy.solveset` (ya le puse a propósito los mismos nombres en los campos de la clase), por lo que puedes pasar directamente ese resultado a la función de plot:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy import solveset, S, latex

ineq = parse_expr("2*x+38 <= 12")
interval = solveset(ineq, domain=S.Reals)

plot_interval(title=latex(ineq, mode="inline"),  
              intervals=[interval],
              color="coral")
```

[image: Resultado]

Y con una pequeña modificación al código anterior se puede detectar cuándo el resultado de simpy es una unión, para convertirlo en la lista apropiada:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy import solveset, S, latex
import sympy

ineq = parse_expr("x**2 > 4")

interval = solveset(ineq, domain=S.Reals)
if type(interval) == sympy.sets.sets.Union:
  intervals = list(interval.args)
else:
  intervals = [interval]

plot_interval(title=latex(ineq, mode="inline"),  
              intervals=intervals,
              color="coral")
```

[image: Resultado]